# can not save utf8 file in windows server with java

Tags: java, file, text, utf-8, window

I have a simple java application that saves some `String` in `utf-8` encode. 
But when I open that file with notepad and `save as`,it shows it's encode `ANSI`.Now I don't know where is the problem? 
My code that save the file is

```
        File fileDir = new File("c:\\Sample.txt"); 
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8")); 
        out.append("kodehelp UTF-8").append("\r\n");
        out.append("??? UTF-8").append("\r\n");
        out.append("???? UTF-8").append("\r\n"); 
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Comment: The code which you posted above works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters you are writing to the file, as they appear in the code snippet, are in the basic ASCII subset of UFT-8. Notepad is likely auto-detecting the format, and seeing nothing outside the ASCII range, decides the file is ANSI.

If you want to force a different decision, place characters such as `字` or `õ` which are well out of the ASCII range.

It is possible that the `???` strings in your example were intended to be UTF-8. If so. make sure your IDE and/or build tool recognizes the files as UTF-8, and the files are indeed UTF-8 encoded. If you provide more information about your build system, then we can help further.